# CloudWatch Logs in Python Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to put the entry in dynamo-db table,as soon as i put object in S3 file.
I have set the triggers for the same.

I have written simple below lambada code to check the response

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(str(event))
```

When i am checking in CLoudWatchLogs i can see below.

```
{'Records': [{'eventVersion': '2.1', 'eventSource': 'aws:s3', 
'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'eventTime': '2019-02-20T15:58:48.057Z', 
'eventName': 'ObjectCreated:Put', 'userIdentity': {'principalId': 
'AHRO8PUVZ6HA1'}, 'requestParameters': {'sourceIPAddress': 
'106.193.192.255'}, 'responseElements': {'x-amz-request-id': 
'218359C00133F5A3', 'x-amz-id-2': 
 'ZcA26gyzVOaaG+O1AgbZl6UTGjdqxvz0THfeyGepwPwkn8No2m+
 2jCm/zHvMGH1igrATG1pAnQI='}, 's3': {'s3SchemaVersion': '1.0', 
'configurationId': 'd4eeba8b-3cab-43d2-835a-2d6fed343144', 'bucket': 
 {'name': 'trus-bucket-291902', 'ownerIdentity': {'principalId': 
 'AHRO8PUVZ6HA1'}, 'arn': 'arn:aws:s3:::trus-bucket-291902'}, 'object': 
 {'key': 'Linux-admin-Lecture-14.pdf', 'size': 113847, 'eTag': 
'a8b3f353134bfaf7e876e05b439c7632', 'sequencer': '005C6D7937E630A6EB'}}}]}
```

Can you help me fetch the object name(Linux-admin-Lecture-14.pdf) and size (113847) from above string?

Comment: Please format your code sample to look more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is a normal Python dictionary, so it's accessed the usual way

```
key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
```

Comment: Thanks Pasi.I appreciate if you can explain me how you arrive to this so that next time i can do by my own.

Comment: You can look up tutorials explaining python dictionaries, for example: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp You can also go to a Json viewer website that can nicely format it, so that you can see which keys to use to access it (for ex http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ paste your code and hit "format")